# How can I prevent a window from being deactivated?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, focus, activation

Is there any way to prevent a window from being deactivated? The window is in a different process then mine.

This is for Windows.

Comment: The key to answering such questions is: what if two applications tried to do that?

Comment: @Sasha: +1. Also, "the window is in a different process" sounds like an interesting twist on the basic problem.

Comment: "prevent the window of a different process from being deactivated" sounds like a solution you're trying to make work, rather than the problem - you might get better advice if you can tell us what the underlying problem is.

Answer (score 4):

Doing this can be dangerous, but the solution is to handle the WM_ACTIVATE message and check if the wParam is WA_INACTIVE. This means the window has been deactivated. When this happens, you can just reactivate it.

In order to do this for another process's window, you will need to install a message hook with `SetWindowsHookEx`.

However, it is possible that another application could do the same thing, putting each other in an endless loop of activation/deactivation.

This is also something that should never be done by software that is meant to run on a personal computer.

Comment: More importantly, it's a hard rule in Windows that you're not supposed to change the focus during a focus-changing event. `WM_ACTIVATE` is merely a notification that the window is changing activation states: **it's not asking for permission**. You don't really have any say in the matter, and assuming that you do is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can trap the [`WM_ACTIVATEAPP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632614%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) like this:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
  // Trap WM_ACTIVATEAPP
  if ((m.Msg == 0x1c) && (m.WParam == IntPtr.Zero))
  {
     // If WM_ACTIVATEAPP and WParam is deactivated, return
     return;
  }
  base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: The question called for a windows in a different process. Your code will only work for a window in the same process (as the code).

Comment: Are you sure this works? The other application is receiving a `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` message at the same time. This message isn't asking for permission to deactivate the app.