# How can I disable specific Windows hotkeys from inside a software using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, hotkeys

I want to put inside a software the necessary codes for it to disable Windows (Xp, Vista, specially 7 and sucessors) hotkeys that could allow the user to get away from the software.

Details:

- The commands must be valid only while the software is running; when its not running, Windows hotkeys must be enabled (so: if the user starts the software, the hotkeys are disable; if he closes it, must be re-enabled).
- I don't want to disable all windows hotkeys (some key hotkeys such as ctrl+alt+del must still be operational), so solutions such as some sort of windows configuration that disable all hotkeys are useless for me. I must be capable of specifically select which hotkeys I want to continue working and which I don't.
- The "hotkey" nickname includes the Windows button.
- The code must be either using C++ or Windows functions.
- Preferetially without requiering to terminate explorer.exe.

I did look at a post here in stackoverflow that had a very similiar case as mine ([Prevent users from quitting a windows application via system hotkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082524/prevent-users-from-quitting-a-windows-application-via-system-hotkeys)), but as far as I understood nether of the solutions presented were applicable to my specific situation, and I didn't find anything in the web as well.

Comment: unclear to me:  the application will only get keystrokes when it has focus... do you mean to subvert that?

Comment: This sounds exactly like you need a hook.

Comment: Inorder for this to work, you need to remove the ability of users to change focus, which is possible.  Think those stupid demo apps at on laptops at bestbuy.  take a look at the answer to this question http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Randy: there are some hotkeys that are enable independent on the focus to a application - alt+tab, e.g.. I want to disable a couple of them.

Comment: @chris: yeah, that's one of the most found solutions in the web, and I'm currently studying them. The unique problem is that the examples I found are not thaaat clear in explaining. Worst, they all talk about hooks related to 1 key, but not to combination of keys (e.g. alt+tab).

Comment: @8bitwide: How exactly one can remove the ability to change focus? That would be great!

Comment: @Momergil, You can capture the windows/alt key and store its state, then capture other keys when it's down. As for focus, it's not the best idea, but handling `WM_KILLFOCUS` to set it again might work.

Comment: @Momergil read the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142515/how-can-i-prevent-a-window-from-being-deactivated and the link I left above.  It will require so windows api use, which can be a headache if your not accustomed to it.

Comment: @8bitwide, I'm not sure if I could have any usage of the link you provided. My problem persist :T

Comment: you should really think what you are doing from a UX point of view. If I used an app and saw that I cannot quit it or change focus to another app using the usual methods or by some simple and clear way I would kill it instantly and never ever used it again. Antivirus scan might be thrown in the mix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I got how to do it. The code is able to create a sistem-wide hook without DLL using a low level keyboard hook. Here is the code (better that explaining)(using Qt):

```
//Installing the hook
SWH_return = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,LowLevelKeyboardProc,GetModuleHandle(NULL),0);

if (SWH_return != NULL)
    qDebug() << "Hook true";
else
    qDebug() << "Hook false";

//Uninstalling the hook
bool teste = false;

teste = UnhookWindowsHookEx(SWH_return);

if (teste)
    qDebug() << "Unhook: true";
else
    qDebug() << "Unhook: false";

//The function responsible for detecting the keystrokes
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
if (nCode < 0)
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);

tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *str = (tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;

switch(str->flags)
{
    case (LLKHF_ALTDOWN):
        qDebug() << "ALT";
        delete str;
    return 1;
}

if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
{
    switch (str->vkCode)
    {
        case VK_RWIN:
        case VK_LWIN:
        case VK_LCONTROL:
        case VK_RCONTROL:
        case VK_APPS:
        case VK_SLEEP:
        case VK_MENU:
            qDebug() << "SPECIAL PRESS";
            delete str;
        return 1;
    }
}

return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This last function don't need any declaration in the .h or in the .cpp file. It blocks inputs of Ctrl, Windows Key and Alt. The other two must be placed respectively in the functions where the user wants to begin the key disabling and when he want it to stop.

Thanks,

Momergil.

Comment: I see you call "delete str;". Is this right? I tried myself and got access violation?

Comment: @BillYan: Obviously not right. It's a pointer to a Windows structure, allocated by the OS itself. In particular, it's not allocated by `new` (just check the example, no `new tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT` to be found). So `delete` is plain wrong. Why this answer is accepted? It's self-answered, i.e. Momergil wrote the question, this answer, and then marked his _own_ answer as correct. Indeed, despite the glaring bug.

Answer (score 0):

RegisterHotKey is also globally disable hotkey for all applications except where RegisterHotKey function call is made.

```
RegisterHotKey(GetSafeHwnd(), 100, 0,VK_F5); //F5 works only in our application
```