# Not being able to use SetWindowsHookEx with LowLevelKeyboardProc in Borland C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, setwindowshookex

I'm developing a software which must block some keyboard inputs while its running. Since I've talked about some problems surrending this wish, I'll not repeat details here (for a better understanding of the circunstances, just read this: [How can I disable specific Windows hotkeys from inside a software using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352343/how-can-i-disable-specific-windows-hotkeys-from-inside-a-software-using-c/11994703#11994703))

My current problem now is that I was able to do what I want with Qt, and now I must pass it to Borland C++ Builder 6, but Builder's compiler is refusing the code:

```
SWH_return = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,LowLevelKeyboardProc,GetModuleHandle(NULL),0);
```

pointing out

> [C++ Error] FrmMain.cpp(155): E2034 Cannot convert 'long (__stdcall *)(int,unsigned int,long)' to 'int (__stdcall *)()'

This is very strange, once Qt finds no problem whatsoever with this line of code and everything runs fine. The problem is about the inclusion of "LowLevelKeyboardProc" in "SetWindowsHookEx". I've tried some changes in the code, without success.

Could somebody give me a help with this?

Thanks,

Momergil

Note: for more details about the code, just visit the link I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I think this relates to not having the preprocessor macro `STRICT` defined.

But, the easy workaround is to cast the function pointer to a `HOOKPROC`.

```
SWH_return = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC)LowLevelKeyboardProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved - despite maybe not as one would expect...

Borland Builder c++ 6 is from year 2002, and comparing Builder's Compiler's version of the winuser.h file (where HOOKPROC is defined) and Qt's winuser.h I noticed that they were totally different one from the other, as one would expect it since it was been 10 years since Microsoft released Builder's version of the file.

So everthing I had to do was to comment Builder's winuser.h line where HOOKPROC was declared and ctrl+c/ctrl+v Qt's winuser.h version of HOOKPROC's definition, and it worked fine.

I don't think, though, that this would be the most "politically correct" way of solving this problem, but anyway it worked.

Thanks,

Momergil